# How can I remove datestamped files with Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I have a folder with multiple PDFs with datestamps at the end of their names e.g.

```
hello_20200820.pdf
hello_20200821.pdf
hello_20200822.pdf
hello_20200717.pdf
```

I am trying to write a function to remove all the PDFs in the folder other than the TWO most recent pdf's.

The code I have written however is deleting the only the 3rd most recent file or the oldest file if there are less than 3. How can I fix this and remove ALL pdfs with the name 'hello' other than the two most recent?

Here is my code so far:

```
def remove_old_pdf(wsp, folder):
    date_diff = float('inf')
    today = datetime.now()
    filename = ''

    files = os.listdir('PDFs/' + folder)
    # print(files)
    for file in files:

        if file.endswith('.pdf') and wsp in file:
            date_str = file.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
            curr_diff = today - datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d')

            if date_diff == float('inf') or curr_diff < date_diff:
                date_diff = curr_diff
                filename = file
                # print(filename)
            else:
                pass

    print(filename)
    files.remove(filename)
    # print(files)

    for file in files:

        if file.endswith('.pdf') and wsp in file:
            date_str = file.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
            curr_diff = today - datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d')

            filename = file
        else:
            pass

    if filename in files:
        files.remove(filename)
        print(filename)
    else:
        print('lol')
    # print(files)

    for file in files:

        if file.endswith('.pdf') and wsp in file:
            date_str = file.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
            curr_diff = today - datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d')

            filename = file
        else:
            pass

    delFile = 'PDFs/' + folder + '/' + filename
    finalFiles = os.listdir('PDFs/' + folder)
    if filename in finalFiles:
        os.remove('PDFs/' + folder + '/' + filename)
        print('Deleted ' + filename +'.')
    else:
        print("No PDFs deleted")
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  In short, trace the mechanics of *how* your code selects only that one file; don't leave us to do your trace and isolation.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can provide that considering it requires a folder filled with datestamped PDFs. Sorry if this code isn't enough

Comment: To make this a proper MRE, you write a simple loop to create several such dummy files.  Since your program requires that folder, then write code to create that situation.  However, you haven't addressed my main issue; lack of trying to trace the problem yourself.  You've pushed all of that setup and diagnostic work on everyone who would try to help you.

Comment: Essentially I'm certain I am approaching this problem the completely wrong way and my code is likely not close to the proper solution. My question is more how can I remove all pdfs with a certain phrase in the name (e.g. 'hello') that are not the two most recent datestamp files.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to do that sorry Prune

Comment: Well, you have a little research to do, then.  You also still have tracing work to do.  If the problem is straightforward enough, then the tracing will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob` to list all the files that match, restrict to the first `n-2` and delete those:

```
import os
from glob import glob

dryrun = True  # change this to False to actually delete
wc = 'hello_????????.pdf'

for name in sorted(glob(wc))[:-2]:
    print(f'delete {name}{" (DRY-RUN)" if dryrun else ""}')
    if not dryrun:
        os.unlink(name)
```

Note: personally I always prefer to have globs that are as strict as possible. So I often define something like:

```
wildcards = {
    'Y': '[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]',
    'm': '[01][0-9]',
    'd': '[0-3][0-9]',
    'H': '[0-2][0-9]',
    'M': '[0-5][0-9]',
    'S': '[0-5][0-9]',
}

# and then:
ymdglob = ''.join([wildcards[datepart] for datepart in 'Ymd'])
wc = f'hello_{ymdglob}.pdf'

# etc.
```

Comment: Is there a way to account for any text that might occur after the expected 'hello' but before the '_'?

Comment: sure, use `'*'` to match 0 or more chars, see the doc for `glob`. But be careful, wildcards are far less powerful that regex. So often we use a combination of both: a relatively loose wildcard match, and then a stricter regex match inside the loop. It is also fairly common to parse the date from the name. BTW I assume you are talking about the date from the filename, that can be completely different than the actual file's `mtime` (beware).

Comment: I assume the '*' would go on the wc = line ? Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Yes. But you should really check what you are deleting --put some constraints & checks etc. and refuse loudly to delete anything unexpected. Examples of constraints: total size and number of files about to be deleted; length of each filename, types of characters in the "free text" part that was matched by `'*'`, etc.